# Only first collectionViewCell reacts to user interactions

Tags: ios, swift

### The setup

I have a rather complex view hierarchy which made me do terrible things with `tableViews` and `collectionViews`. Right now I'm having a regular grouped `TableView` with custom `TableCells.` `TableCell` itself contains a couple of views and a `Collection View.` The height of the table cell is calculated based on number of items in the data source. On its creation `table cell` creates a `collection view` with a calculated size to fit necessary data.

-- `UITableView`

---- `UITableViewCell`

------ `UICollectionView`

--------- `UICollectionViewCell`

### The problem

I've encountered unusual problem with a custom `collectionViewCell`. I have a vertical single-column `collectionView` with dynamic amount of cells.  Ideally tapping on the cell should call didSelectItemAt. The cell also has three buttons. Tapping on the button should trigger some action. All of the desired functions work only for a first cell. The rest of the cells are not responsive to any actions.

### Things that look strange

By default the scrolling of a `collectionView` inside of the `tableViewCell` is disabled because it basically fits all the content based on calculated height and doesn't require scrolling. (Also I don't want it to interfere with tableView scrolling logic).

**First**

I've tried to hardcode some value for the height of collectionView and enable scrolling. What happened is a mystery for me.

Let's say that calculated height required for the `collectionView` to show all the content **without** scrolling is `740`. When I manually set it to be `280` (this is enough for exactly 2 cells to fit) and enabled scrolling my first cell were still working, but also when I scrolled collection just a little bit my second cell started to act normally as well. When I scrolled back to the top of the collectionView it was disabled once again.

So it looks like when the scrolling is enabled and will actually occur because of insufficient height to fit the content, cells behave as they should. As soon as I set height of the collectionView to be enough to fit its content, things go wrong.

**Second**

In some cases I can actually tap on the second cell and it will call the delegate. But the weird thing is it works when I tap in the top area of the cell, like 10pts from the top. The other areas of the cell are unresponsive so are the rest of the cells in the collection.

The working delegates and buttons with enabled scrolling forces to think that this has nothing to do with delayed or canceled touches. The frame for collectionView and height of the table cell are calculated properly as well.

**xCode 8.3, iOS9+**

Comment: You will likely need to provide some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Well there're just too many code. But while waiting for an answer I just found the solution. I will add it as answer soon. Thank you for investing your time in this question.

Comment: For future reference: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add the answer and mark is accepted so that not everyone waste their time reading the question.

Comment: @PGDev already did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out when I was creating my `tableViewCell`, I hardcoded the height of the collection to value of 214. The reason for that is very simple. I create a cell programmatically and with `tableViewCells` created programmatically the height of the cell is always 44. When you override `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`

You need to either hardcore the height, or update it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Even though I updated `collection` frame when it was filled with data, the container view of this `collection` wasn't updated resulting in some sort of clipping area for user interactions.